# Fatterned List in Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Like to convert following data into single list in dict. If the dict key already exits in list in the list and value is the same, do not add it.

```
data1 = 
"""
    [{'In': ['5,000 MByte']},
     {'Out': ['155 MByte', '10,100 MByte']},
     {'Total': ['5,000 MByte']},}]
"""


Expected:
```

```
[{'In': '5,000 MByte',
 'Out': '155 MByte',
 'Total': '5,000 MByte'}]
```

Comment: Trying to get the multiple values.. updated.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
data1 = """
[{'In': ['5,000 MByte']},
{'Out': ['155 MByte', '10,100 MByte']},
{'Total': ['5,000 MByte']}]
"""

import ast
data1_dict = {}

for item in ast.literal_eval(data1):
    for key in item:
        data1_dict[key] = item[key][0]

res = [data1_dict]
print(res)
```